# Metal performance shaders: what type is the return of the MPSImageHistogram's output buffer

Tags: swift, metal

I'm trying to get some histogram info from the MPSImageHistogram metal performance shader as the buffer is a pointer which I need to convert to something using the unbind(type.slef, capacity: Int).pointee process. I don't know if it's a struct, an array, of floats, a dict, nothing. The MPSImageHistogram library reference only refers to a buffer that can then be used to equalize or specify a given histogram, but no link or reference to the resulting histogram.

Comment: It is good practice to include some source code (even if only pseudo-code) so that we can see how things are actually being used.

Comment: Not only have I written what I am asking for, but have answered. Please review

Comment: I was just trying to fully understand your question, which of course isn't needed any more. Hopefully my tip about using the same format as the MTLTexture pixel format helped you.

Answer (score 0):

So for reference and completeness as I found out through some investigation:

NPSImageHistogram requires an MPSHistogram struct that holds information about the desired histogram parameters, such as bins per channel, threshold value, max value and a color transform, optionally.

The return type is then a reflection of the MTLBuffer structure which is declared using the memory layout of the desired bins, in the case of a RGBA image using all 256 possible values per channel per pixel, this will be 4*256, or MemoryLayout<UInt32_t>.stride*4*256

The buffer's output content will then have to be declared as below:

```
let histogramPointer = buffer.content.bind(to: UInt32_t.self, capacity: 4*256).pointee
```

To loop through all the values, de-reference the pointer with .pointee and go through each using indexing by first creating an UnsafeBuffer with the dereferenced pointer as below:

```
let arrayPointer = UnsafeBuffer(start: histogramPointer, count: 4*256)
let histogramArray = Array(arrayPointer) 

for i in histogramArray {
...
}
```